# View create statement executed before table create statements

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database with 6 tables. These tables are created with the help of a content provider and a database helper. When I run the app with these 6 tables the app works, all tables are created and I can query the tables and insert data just fine.

However, when I try to add an sqlite view to the onCreate method of my database helper the app crashes.

From what I can understand, the view's onCreate method is for whatever reason getting called before the tables onCreate methods used in the View's Join.

What I need to know is how do I force my databaseHelper to first create the tables and then creating the view.

Due to the nature of the question (the word "view" is used to refer to something else) I am having a hard time trying to find a solution.

This is the code to create the view:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "recent_listens";

public static final String TIMESTAMP_ID = timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_ID;
public static final String TRACK_NAME = trackTable.TRACK_NAME;
public static final String TRACK_MBID = trackTable.TRACK_MBID;
public static final String ALBUM_NAME = albumTable.ALBUM_NAME;
public static final String ALBUM_MBID = albumTable.ALBUM_MBID;
public static final String ARTIST_NAME = artistTable.ARTIST_NAME;
public static final String ARTIST_MBID = artistTable.ARTIST_MBID;
public static final String TIMESTAMP_VALUE = timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_VALUE;
public static final String IMAGE_ID = albumTable.ALBUM_IMG_ID;

private static final String LISTEN_VIEW_CREATE = ""
        + "CREATE VIEW " + TABLE_NAME + " AS "
        + "SELECT "
            + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_ID + " AS " + TIMESTAMP_ID + ", "
            + trackTable.TRACK_NAME + " AS " + TRACK_NAME + ", "
            + trackTable.TRACK_MBID + " AS " + TRACK_MBID + ", "
            + albumTable.ALBUM_NAME + " AS " + ALBUM_NAME + ", "
            + albumTable.ALBUM_MBID + " AS " + ALBUM_MBID + ", "
            + artistTable.ARTIST_NAME + " AS " + ARTIST_NAME + ", "
            + artistTable.ARTIST_MBID + " AS " + ARTIST_MBID + ", "
            + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_VALUE + " AS " + TIMESTAMP_VALUE + ", "
            + albumTable.ALBUM_IMG_ID + " AS " + IMAGE_ID
        + " FROM "
            + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP
                + " INNER JOIN " + trackTable.TABLE_TRACK + " ON "
                    + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_CON_TRACK_ID + " = "
                    + trackTable.TABLE_TRACK + "." + trackTable.TRACK_ID
                + " INNER JOIN " + albumTable.TABLE_ALBUM + " ON "
                    + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_CON_ALBUM_ID + " = "
                    + albumTable.TABLE_ALBUM + "." + albumTable.ALBUM_ID;

public static synchronized void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(LISTEN_VIEW_CREATE);
```

And this is the error I get:

**Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: artist_name (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW recent_listens AS SELECT timestamps_table._id AS _id, track_name AS track_name, track_mbid AS track_mbid, album_name AS album_name, album_mbid AS album_mbid, artist_name AS artist_name, artist_mbid AS artist_mbid, timestamp AS timestamp, album_img_id AS album_img_id FROM timestamps_table INNER JOIN tracks ON timestamps_table.track_id = tracks._id INNER JOIN albums ON timestamps_table.album_id = albums._id**

Here is my databaseHelper class:

```
public class databaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userData.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

public databaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    artistTable.onCreate(database);
    albumTable.onCreate(database);
    trackTable.onCreate(database);
    tagTable.onCreate(database);
    similarTable.onCreate(database);
    timestampTable.onCreate(database);
    listenView.onCreate(database);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    artistTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    albumTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    trackTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    tagTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    similarTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    timestampTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    listenView.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

}

This is called in my custom content provider onCreate method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    database = new databaseHelper(getContext());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: BTW why patch your query together like this? Isn't that really painful? Just write it up in one piece.

Comment: The problem is in the artistTable code that you have not shown.

Comment: @CL I think the problem is I didn't include the artistTable in the join. I am checking to see if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: artist_name
```

this makes it obvious that your view tries to access a column which does not exists in that table (I think timestamps_table). Most likely you get this because you added `artist_name` table and forgot to increment new version of the database in `onUpgrade()`.
The fix: upgrade db's version or uninstall the app and run it again or clear app's data from settings

Comment: The column is in another table which is successfully created when I remove the CREATE VIEW statement from the database helper. The problem I have is that the view is getting created before any other table. Also, I have cleared the app data multiple times, it does not help.

Comment: can you please provide more details from onCreate() ? to me it looks like the first thing you create is the view even though first you should create the tables. Thanks !

Comment: Added my databaseHelper class to the question

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else will encounter the same problem, I am going to leave this up.

It turns out I didn't include a table in the join which was mentioned in the select.

The resulting View create string is this:

```
private static final String LISTEN_VIEW_CREATE = ""
        + "CREATE VIEW " + TABLE_NAME + " AS "
        + "SELECT "
            + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_ID + " AS " + LISTEN_ID + ", "
            + trackTable.TRACK_NAME + " AS " + TRACK_NAME + ", "
            + trackTable.TRACK_MBID + " AS " + TRACK_MBID + ", "
            + albumTable.ALBUM_NAME + " AS " + ALBUM_NAME + ", "
            + albumTable.ALBUM_MBID + " AS " + ALBUM_MBID + ", "
            + artistTable.ARTIST_NAME + " AS " + ARTIST_NAME + ", "
            + artistTable.ARTIST_MBID + " AS " + ARTIST_MBID + ", "
            + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_VALUE + " AS " + TIMESTAMP_VALUE + ", "
            + albumTable.ALBUM_IMG_ID + " AS " + IMAGE_ID
        + " FROM "
            + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP
                + " INNER JOIN " + trackTable.TABLE_TRACK + " ON "
                    + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_CON_TRACK_ID + " = "
                    + trackTable.TABLE_TRACK + "." + trackTable.TRACK_ID
                + " INNER JOIN " + albumTable.TABLE_ALBUM + " ON "
                    + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_CON_ALBUM_ID + " = "
                    + albumTable.TABLE_ALBUM + "." + albumTable.ALBUM_ID
                + " INNER JOIN " + artistTable.TABLE_ARTIST + " ON "
                    + timestampTable.TABLE_TIMESTAMP + "." + timestampTable.TIMESTAMP_CON_ARTIST_ID + " = "
                    + artistTable.TABLE_ARTIST + "." + artistTable.ARTIST_ID;
```